# Организовали отдых туристов или туристам?

Tags: грамматика, окончания

Как правильно "организовали отдых более 3000 туристам" или "организовали отдых более 3000 туристов"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно так: *организовали отдых более **чем** 3000 туристов*.

Comment: А почему? Добавьте, пжста, ссылку на правило

Comment: Нет ссылки. А как по-другому?

Comment: Уменьшите число, чтобы понять.

Comment: Форму вы выбрали правильно (я вам даже плюс поставлю).  Просто интересно, почему здесь Р.п. конкурирует с Т.п.

Comment: Изначально ориентировался просто на своё чувство языка. Но получается так: *Организовали отдых {3 туристов}. Организовали отдых 3 туристам.* В первом случае относится к словосочетанию, это неуместно.

Comment: Какое управление верно: отдых туристов или отдых туристам?

Comment: Ну так там есть число, а у вас — нет. Вы же не скажете так: *Они организовали отдых туристов.* Как-то разговорно звучит.

Comment: Меня интересует, каким падежом управляет "отдых". как правильно: организовать отдых детей или отдых детям .Организовали отдых  трем туристам или трех туристов

Comment: Родительный падеж, конечно. А если дательный, то управление идёт от глагола. Управление от "отдых" — разговорный вариант (не особо правильно, но поймут).

Comment: Смотрю, что *отдых кого-то* не особо удачно в плане стилистики. Например: *Отдых детей прошёл удачно.* Надо так: *Отдых у детей прошёл удачно.* Но в примере из вопроса нет второго варианта, как в ваших примерах, потому что там записано цифрами.

Comment: Сравните: Организовали отдых (кому) трестам туристам или отдых  (кого) трехсот туристов. Здесь надо знать правильный падеж. Но когда появляются "тысячи", то  только Р.п., выбора уже нет, так как сущ. "тысяча" управляет только Р.п. Я думаю, что именно это автор вопроса не понимает.

Comment: Но в вопросе об этом не спрашивалось) Там спрашивается о правильном варианте, а не в общем. Но в комментариях уже рассмотрено (*кого* откидываю из-за проблем со стилистикой). Тоже есть выбор: *организовали отдых более чем трём тысячам / трёх тысяч туристов*.